# Display raw HTML and keep word wrapping (cannot use <script> tag)

Tags: html, word-wrap

I need to display this chunk of code as is, (raw) AND it needs to word wrap still. No JavaScript is allowed either, as their system instantly cancels it during publishing. So it's HTML only. And the reason I'm trying to show it raw so it can be copy/pasted and used.

I've tried the following:

1. [Is this the solution?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGdjT.png)
   [It has this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOjcY.png): The `<xmp>` tag displays raw, but doesn't word wrap as seen below (which I think Looks Hilarious).
2. `textarea readonly=true...` Also not good. [This solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0GyH.png) has  [this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arW1Z.png).
3. `<pre>` displays HTML effects but doesn't word wrap.. so no either (basically does what `<xmp>` did).
4. The `//` also has no effect
5. Indenting and block quote were also ineffective.

Need-less to say, I'm stumped folks and need a solution.

Examples are in the images in the links.
(It's crazy: All I need to do here is press space 4 times, wish it were that simple there)

```
<canvas width="1" height="1" style="border: 0px 
dashed blue; box-shadow: 100px 150px 400px 500px rgba(0,256,0,0.2);">
</canvas> <bold><b><strong><big><span style="color: red;">Have you ever 
wanted to change the background color of your post cause boring old white is 
well.... boring, well here ya go :) Just copy and paste the code below into 
your HTML editor when making a post. and change the value's to what ever you 
want!</span></big></strong></bold></canvas>
```

Comment: Important to note this is not necessarily about raw HTML but about the specfic RTE you are using there, so it might be important to add info about it. Also something you might want to try is to use html encoding on those parts.

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace the HTML related characters with HTML entities? That would render in the browser like plain text and behave just like text in terms of word wrapping style.

https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

**Actual Text**

`&lt;canvas width="1" height="1" style="border: 0px 
dashed blue; box-shadow: 100px 150px 400px 500px rgba(0,256,0,0.2);"&gt;
&lt;/canvas&gt;&lt;bold&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;big&gt;&lt;span style="color: red;"&gt;Have you ever
wanted to change the background color of your post cause boring old white is
well.... boring, well here ya go :) Just copy and paste the code below into
your HTML editor when making a post. and change the value's to what ever you 
want!&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/big&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/bold>&lt;/canvas&gt;`

**Displayed in the Browser**

<canvas width="1" height="1" style="border: 0px 
dashed blue; box-shadow: 100px 150px 400px 500px rgba(0,256,0,0.2);">
</canvas><bold><b><strong><big><span style="color: red;">Have you ever
wanted to change the background color of your post cause boring old white is
well.... boring, well here ya go :) Just copy and paste the code below into
your HTML editor when making a post. and change the value's to what ever you 
want!</span></big></strong></bold></canvas>

Comment: thats a good idea, id rather keep it simple for the poker players lol. they do alot of blogging, and considering i cant poker to well, i will offer design tips for poker tips lol. thanks i'll try it out